# Scrollable tabs unable to handle overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
 
    $scope.slideIndex = 0;

            // Called each time the slide changes
        $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {
            $scope.slideIndex = index;
            

            

        };

        $scope.activeSlide = function (index) {
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
        };
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('https://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

.slide-tab{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00897B;

}

.slide-tab li{
    float: left;
    line-height: 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.slide-tab a{
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00897B;
}
.current a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #00897B;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Ionic Slide Tab</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Slide Tab</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="slide-tab">
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 0 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(0)">Tab01</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 1 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(1)">Tab02</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 2 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(2)">Tab03</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 3 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(3)">Tab04</a>
          
          </li>
          <li ng-class="slideIndex == 4 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(4)">Tab05</a></li>
          <li ng-class="slideIndex == 5 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(5)">Tab06</a></li>
          <li ng-class="slideIndex == 6 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(6)">Tab07</a></li>
 
        </ul>
        </div>
        <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" active-slide="slideIndex" class="padding">
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 1</h3>
              <p>Page 1</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 2</h3>
               <p>Page 2</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 3</h3>
               <p>Page 3</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 4</h3>
               <p>page 4</p>
            </ion-slide>
           <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 5</h3>
               <p>page 5</p>
            </ion-slide>
           <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 6</h3>
               <p>page 6</p>
            </ion-slide>
           <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 7</h3>
               <p>page 7</p>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have the snippet as below for Ionic 1. In mobile screen which is small, it will not able to shows all 7 tabs at once. So, it will display as two rows of tabs which is not tidy.

I want the tabs that when scroll the page to the end of the right or left, it can handle overflow so that user will notice there are tabs there.
Example is the [scroollable tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) for android in java. However, I need it in ionic 1.

Comment: Where are you importing Angular? There is an error in your code 'Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined'

Comment: @Manuel I do not see an error. Where do you see an error? The snippet work fine

Comment: If you click on 'Run code snippet' you will see it.

Comment: the snippet is run without error from myside. I am not sure why there is an error from your side run it.

Comment: or you can copy the code to codepen and try